# What is the difference between "Linux Kernel API", "System Calls", "System Interfaces" and "GNU C Library"?

Tags: c++, c, linux

After try to implement a `System Call`, I totally confused about Linux :D

What is the difference between `Linux Kernel API`, `System Calls`, `System Interfaces` and `GNU C Library`?

I found these links for each item:

**The Linux Kernel API**

https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api.html

**Linux System Calls**

http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl

**System Interfaces**

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/functions.html

**The GNU C Library**

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html

I confused about these functions.

For example `sprintf` exists in `Linux Kernel API`, but `System Interfaces` functions list contains this function too. Some functions should not use in Kernel mode (eg. `printf`). Many functions do the same task with different names (eg. `sys_open` and `open`), and so on...

My question is:

What is the difference between `Linux Kernel API`, `System Calls`, `System Interfaces` and `GNU C Library`?
Which function should I use, Which function I should not use?

Oh! I forgot the `C standard library` :)

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].  SO is for specific questions, and not really a tutorial or discussion site.

Comment: As you already have finished collecting all those links, you now have the time to read what they are referring to, haven't you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- The C library implements the C language standard. This is done by calling operating-specific functions, say, for writing to the standard output. The C library can be and has been implemented on many, many systems, such as Linux, Windows, DOS, and various micro controllers.

  The term "GNU C library" presumably refers to a particular implementation of the C library, perhaps the one shipped with the GNU compiler collection.
- The operating system exposes a standard interface, which in Linux is done via *system calls*. So for example, writing to the standard output is done by calling the `write` system call. Linux (and more generally Posix) provide a C library around the system calls to make them convenient to use.

  Using this system interface allows you to implement the C library. For example, `putc` from the C library can be implemented with the `write` system call to file descriptor `1`.

  MS Windows offers an analogous systems API, called the Windows API. It too can be used to implement the C library.
- The kernel API is for programming inside the kernel, e.g. for writing drivers, or for providing new system calls.